# Jquery flot bars reverse y asix

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I can't create flot bars with reverse y asix.

From the point of this helps:

```
transform: function (v) {return -v; },
inverseTransform: function (v) { return -v; }
```

Вut the graphics just flips,
example: http://jsbin.com/eloven/2/edit

Help please!

Comment: wat do mean??..am seeing bars reverse???

Comment: min ~ 200, max: 0. bar with 46point > 100point

Comment: then why dont you just manipulate data...like say 100point bar shld be less than 46point..take some max num. say 150...subtract the data and pass it to graph..

Comment: I don't understand how to organize it. So I use the plugin. Can be an example? Thank you.

Comment: thing is that plugin dont help the way you wanted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:** 0 - (currentValue - maxValue)

```
#graph-bars .bar-wrap {
    height: 45px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9D9D9C;
    position: relative;
}

#graph-bars .bar {
    background: #808080;
    color: #808080;
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 5px;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20%;
}

Array.max = function( array ) {
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};

for(...) {// i -counter
    var max = Array.max(years[lastYear]);
    var height = 0 - (years[lastYear][i] - max); // 0 - (currentValue - maxValue)

    $('#graph-bars').append("<span class='bar-wrap'><span class='bar' style='height:"+ height +"%'></span>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is what you mean by reverse y axis (11, 10 , 9 ... 1),

```
xaxis: {
    transform: function(v) {
        return -v;
    },
    inverseTransform: function(v) {
        return -v;
    }
},
yaxis: {
    show: true,
    tickSize: 200

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this x asix reverse.
I'm trying to y asix reverse: bar with 46point > 100point.